# Bundle install doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, bundler, gemfile

I'm trying to install all gems in a gemFile of a project, but when i typed: 
**sudo bundle install**

but i got this error: 
**Could not find gem 'llrp_connector (>= 0)' ruby in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.**

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=llrp_connector It doesn't look like that gem exists.

Comment: you're right, it was a local gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added this line on the top of your Gemfile?

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

**EDIT**

As Dylan said, this gem doesn't exist on RubyGems.org. If it is a gem hosted on a (private) repository, add it this way :

```
gem "nokogiri", :git => "git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git", :branch => "1.4"
```